# How to reorganize dataframe for a different view of data

Tags: pandas

I have a `dataframe` that has columns like this:

```
   pSpot        quoteDatetime underlyingSymbol           expiration  strike optionType  bid  ask  underlyingBid  underlyingAsk     iv  id
0   0.26  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     600          P  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 178.34 nan
0   0.29  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     650          P  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 173.20 nan
0   0.31  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     700          P  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 168.06 nan
0   0.33  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     750          P  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 162.92 nan
0   1.00  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     2280         C  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 157.79 nan
0   1.01  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00     2300         C  NaN  NaN        2277.40        2278.08 157.79 nan
.....
More data with different expiration dates
```

How do I reorganize the `dataframe` so that it displays `pSpot` and `optionType` columns along the left, and pivots all the expiry and iv from several rows into one row:

```
pSpot optionType   first expiry        iv      second expiry        iv      ... n-expiry              iv
.26       P        2017-01-20T00:00:00 178.34  2017-03-20T00:00:00  125.33      2017-09-20T00:00:00   101.23 
...      ...          ...                ...                         ...                ...
1.01      C        2017-01-20T00:00:00 157.79  2017-03-20T00:00:00  145.45      2017-09-20T00:00:00   132.98
```

Go from stacked or record format, to a pivot of the expiry.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't go along with your expected input. Where did `pSpot` value of `90` come from? also what's `iv` column and its values?

Comment: Please see edit. I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter Series, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then flatten columns names by `f-string`s and last add `pSpot` values, seems first values per groups created by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and for first new column add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
g = df.groupby('optionType').cumcount()

df1 = (df.set_index(['optionType', g])[['expiration','iv']]
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.insert(0,'pSpot', df.drop_duplicates('optionType')['pSpot'].to_numpy())
#oldier pandas versions  
#df1.insert(0,'pSpot', df.drop_duplicates('optionType')['pSpot'].values)
print (df1)
   pSpot optionType          expiration0     iv0          expiration1     iv1  \
0   0.26          C  2017-01-20T00:00:00  157.79  2017-01-20T00:00:00  157.79   
1   1.00          P  2017-01-20T00:00:00  178.34  2017-01-20T00:00:00  173.20   

           expiration2     iv2          expiration3     iv3  
0                  NaN     NaN                  NaN     NaN  
1  2017-01-20T00:00:00  168.06  2017-01-20T00:00:00  162.92
```